# Setting up WiFi with an adapter on a RPI Model B

Tags: networking, wifi

I have a RPI Model B (Revision 000e) running stretch lite (command line only) and with up-to-date software and firmware. I would like to enable WiFi by using a Sitecom WLAN USB adapter (model wla2000).

When I plug in the WiFi adapter and reboot, the WiFi adapter seems to be recognized:

```
$ ip addr
(...)
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:f6:c7:73:0f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

and

```
$ ifconfig
(...)
wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:0c:f6:c7:73:0f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

However, I can not turn on the WiFi via any of these commands:

```
$ sudo ip link set wlan0 up
$ sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

When I try to set the WiFi legal channels via:

*'$ sudo raspiconfig' -> '4 Localisation Options' -> 'I4 Change Wi-fi
Country'*

I get the error message:

```
Could not communicate with wpa_supplicant
```

The following is in my `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` file:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Unless you say what Pi (try using a standard name rather than inventing one) and what " updated software and firmware" means and network settings you are using it as anyones guess. You could start with [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: Maybe instead of being condescending you could first check some facts. (Model B, revision 000e is not an 'invented' name but perfectly indicates which board I am using - https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/revision-codes/README.md). Furthermore, with updated firmware and software I mean that I ran rpi-update and sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade before trying to get the WiFi adapter to work to indicate that obsolete firmware/software is not the issue here.

Comment: I am sorry that you think this is "condescending" but your description leaves a lot to be desired - not to mention the contradictory title. The fact remains without detail of your network settings is unanswerable.

Comment: `wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>` ... it's already "UP" so you don't need to bring it UP any further.

Answer (score 1):

> "In normal circumstances there is NEVER a need to run rpi-update as it always gets you to the leading edge firmware and kernel and because that may be a testing version it could leave your RPi unbootable". https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=916911#p916911
>   Even the [rpi-update](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update) documentation now warns "Even on Raspbian you should only use this with a good reason. This gets you the latest bleeding edge kernel/firmware."

Answer (score -1):

I just went through (hell) similar experience trying to make internal WiFi to work.This should work for a USB dongle too - not tested.

Here is my take on the whole mess.

1. Forget “official tutorials “ and “raspi-config”.
   ( “cannot communicate with wpa_supplicant “ is a joke )
2. Make sure wpa_supplicant SERVICE is running.
   "wpa_cli" will start it, "Network Manager" may do same - not tested.
3. With what WiFi device will your Rpi be communicating ? Router  / modem?
4. Use Raspi OS GUI “Network Manager” (sic?() to find “the other end of the communication link” - in my case router / modem.
5. Select the device (name /  SSID) and supply password if necessary.
6. Reboot and test.

Of course your mileage will wary.

Comment: `running stretch (command line only)` - so your GUI things wont help :p

Comment: Yes, you can do it the hard way - using CLI - or use GUI and you are done!